# How to reverse-i-search back and forth?

Tags: linux, search

I use reverse-i-search often, and that's cool. Sometime though when pressing Ctrl+r multiple times, I pass the command I am actually looking for. Because Ctrl+r searches backward in history, from newest to oldest, I have to:

cancel,
search again and
stop exactly at the command, without passing it.
While in reverse-i-search prompt, is it possible to search forward, i.e. from where I stand to newest. I naively tried Ctrl+shift+r, no luck. I heard about Ctrl+g but this is not what I am expecting here. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The one-sentence answer: Run `stty -ixon` in your terminal, and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to change the search direction from backward to forward.

The exact answer likely depends on which shell you're using. However, in both bash and Zsh (and probably other shells), you can (in theory) type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to search forward.  Thus, after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> a few too many times, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> a few times to move to the command you actually want. Many terminals, however, trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for [software flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control), so the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> never makes it to bash; if you want bash, rather than your terminal, to read the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, you can disable software flow control by running `stty -ixon`.

Comment: I run bash in a gnome3 terminal. Your solution works for me, I can see `(reverse-i-search)` and `(i-search)` when toggling `Ctrl+s` and `Ctrl+r`. How can I enable software flow control back again? `stty -ixon` does not seem to prevent reverse search from trapping `Ctrl+s`

Comment: You can reenable software flow control using `stty ixon` (without the hyphen).

Comment: Or just rebind **Ctrl+C** to **Ctrl+X** keys with `$ stty stop ^X`  From: http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/11/20/bash-history-reverse-intelligent-search/#comment-157

Answer (score 0):

The terminal interprets the `^S` character as its `STOP` control character instead of passing it on to the shell.

You can change the terminal's `STOP` character with `stty stop ^O` for example. To type `^O` in your terminal / shell, first type `^V`; then type `^O`.

To see the terminal's control characters, type `stty -a`.

References:

1. [https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html#:~:text=shall%20be%20supported%3A-,%2Da,Write%20to%20standard%20output%20all%20the%20current%20settings%20for%20the%20terminal.,-%2Dg](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html#:%7E:text=shall%20be%20supported%3A-,%2Da,Write%20to%20standard%20output%20all%20the%20current%20settings%20for%20the%20terminal.,-%2Dg)
2. https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Modifying-Text
3. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Text